# Hello I'm trying to print time elapsed since posted from a mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Harare');

 function get_timeago($connect, $post_datetime){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_datetime = :post_datetime";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':post_datetime' => $post_datetime
        )
    );
    $timeago = $post_datetime;
    $current_time = time();
    $time_difference = $current_time - $timeago; 
    $seconds = $time_difference;
    $minutes = round($seconds / 60);
    $hours   = round($seconds / 3600);
    $days    = round($seconds / 86400);
    $weeks   = round($seconds / 604800);
    $months  = round($seconds / 2629800); //((365 + 365 + 365 + 366)/4/12) * 24 * 3600
    $years   = round($seconds / 31557600); //$months * 12

    if($seconds <= 60){
        return 'Just Now';
    } else if($minutes <= 60){
        if($minutes == 1){
            return 'a minute ago';
        } else {
            return '$minutes minutes ago';
        }
    } else if($hours <= 60){
        if($hours == 1){
            return 'an hour ago';
        } else {
            return '$hours hrs ago';
        }
    } else if($days <= 7){
        if($days == 1){
            return 'Yesterday';
        } else {
            return '$days days ago';
        }
    } else if($weeks <= 4){
        if($weeks == 1){
            return 'a week ago';
        } else {
            return '$weeks weeks ago';
        }
    } else if($months <= 12){
        if($months == 1){
            return 'a month ago';
        } else {
            return '$months months ago';
        } 
    } else if($years == 1){
        return 'a year ago';
    } else {
        return '$years years ago';
    }
return $result;
}

<span class="description">Shared publicly <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> - '.get_timeago($connect, strtotime($row['post_datetime'])).'</span>

?>
```

it's outputting this instead:

Shared publicly - $minutes minutes ago

Comment: `it's outputting this instead:` which is?  this bit, i guess `Shared publicly - $minutes minutes ago`

Comment: DOUBLE QUOTE will expand $vars but SINGLE QUOTES WILL NOT So `return "$weeks weeks ago";`

Comment: PS: `return $result;` ??? What `$result`????

Comment: I thought the function has to return something that's why i stored the query execution in the $result variable. Think it's supposed to return something but dunno how

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is this

```
 '$years years ago'
```

Well part of it anyway.  In PHP single quotes do not interpolate variables, they are not replaced and are instead treated as string literals.

Instead use the `"` double quote.

```
 $foo = 'replaced';
 echo "$foo"; //outputs replaced

 echo '$foo'; //outputs $foo
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Lemme do what you're saying. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Sure it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix for the help. Changed the single quotes to double quotes and it's now working perfectly.